# Where does the `.ok?` or `.body` come from in assert last_response.ok? Ruby TDD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rack, testunit

I'm exploring Test::Unit and Rack::Test with TDD.  Documentation is hard to find on the exact to-do's when implementing.  I've found so far that you have to start a test with `test_` to `test_check_something`.  Also, 
https://rubydoc.org/stdlib1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html explains `assertions` and http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/MockSession#last_response-instance_method will provide insight on Rack::Test questions, like `last_response` and `last_request`.  However, where is the library or source for the appending `.ok?` or `.body` found.  Further, what exactly are they checking; are they checking HTML tags and HTML responses?

Comment: There's millions of examples to learn from here, pretty much every popular gem has some kind of test suite for it, so I'd encourage you to study those. There's not a whole lot to the mechanics of unit testing, most of the complexity comes in how to write testable code, which is a bit of an art.

Comment: My question is primarily about the chaining of `.ok?`, `.body` among other chained examples.  What can I chain to `last_response`?  An answer can be, "you can chain `.ok?` to it that returns true when the response is `200`.  My next question is then, where is the documentation for `.ok?`

Comment: One question at a time is best, plus it's also important to include code in your question that demonstrates what you're trying to do. Chain it how? In what context?

Comment: I'm not sure how much more clear I can be.  Full code in TDD example, `assert last_response.ok?`.  I've clearly indicated that I found material explaining `assert` and material explaining `last_response`.  My primary question involves the documentation on the chained `.ok?` part among many other options.

Comment: If you want to know where a method comes from: `last_response.method(:ok?).source_location` which will help direct you to the documentation.